# Cakephp Code Generation with bake

Tags: cakephp-bake, cake-console

I have just downloaded cakephp latest version 2.3.0 and trying to create skeleton application 
using bake command. 
Problem is when I execute the command cake bake at /app>cake bake. Following message I am getting:

### Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.2 Console

App : app

### Path: /var/www/cake-acl/app

### Your database configuration was not found. Take a moment to create one.

### Database Configuration:

You can see, console is showing Cakephp version 1.3.2, even I have downloaded 2.3.0, thats why console is trying to create 1.3 version scripts for e.g. app/config folder instead app/Config (2.0 convention).

Why this is happening, Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using v1.3.2 before downloading 2.3.0 version then it is possible that you might have set path for v.1.3.2 in your environment settings. So you need to change that to your latest version.